Why is this vertex not affected by Subdivision modifier?
I can't figure out why one of the vertices on the image below does not "move" when Subdivision modifier is turned on. It causes ugly pinch in the whole mesh. There are no duplicates and I don't remember I was messing with Bevel Weights, Edit Crease etc.
Any idea what may cause it?
I use Blender 4.2.
Thanks















What does the extra edge (going top-right) connect to from that vertex? - You have 5 edges connecting to that vertex while all the others have 4. I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Yes as John says it looks like you have an inner edge, remove it

OMG, of course it is it. I haven't noticed the extra edge there. I have extruded the rounded part and use mirror a couple of times. This is why the edge got there. However, I don't know why it was not removed, since I deleted the vertex and faces around it--I am surprised that edge survived all that :) Cheers!
